# how to separate chapters and section

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I have a lot of chapters and sections inside chapters tex file. I want to make a separate folder for chapter and there put separate sections tex files. How I should do this? I am using **report** for now, so I am just `\include` all chapters files in maintex. I am thinking of changing everything to **book**, but I don't know will it look the same? Or maybe I could stay with **report**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`book` and `report` are the same in this respect, just continue to use `\include` for chapters and then `\input` the files with sections.

Comment: So you offer me to do something like: \include {chapter1} \input {section1} ?

Comment: @Mantas, no I would add the `\input{section1}` inside `chapter1` (though I do not understand why people split chapters into smaller files).

Comment: @Mantas as daleif says, the \input{section} needs to go into the chapter file at the point that you would otherwise have the section text

Comment: @daleif I split it to smaller files, because I am writing c# program with multiple choices of options of which chapters/sections I want to put to my pdf.

Comment: One last question, How to make it work if maintex and chapter folder is in different folders? or chapter and chapter's sections is in different folder?

Comment: @Mantas if the folders are in your input path just `\input{filename}` should work from anywhere, if not then `\input{chapter-folder/filename}` will work (input path is relative to the main file, even if the chapter is in a different folder).